# xpages: is it possible to trap when user logs in?

Tags: xpages, xpages-ssjs

I am writing an app in which the end user can mark documents as his favourites.  I already have the necessary forms and views to save and read back the favorites, but I have one little problem: all is done in the back end (the favorites are displayed from a view, not a scoped variable) and there seems to be a sync issue between the click on the "add to favorites" link and the partial refresh that reloads the favorites: the newly added document only shows after a second refresh.  No problem then, I then decided to move the favorites in a managed bean I already have for the session where I keep the language and other user's prefs.

The problem I now face is this: how can I trap the login event so I can build the favorites list in the bean?  I looked at how the "xInvolve" control's favorite piece was built and I found that there is some code added to the custom control's beforePageLoad event.  But I'm wandering if there's a better way of doing this.  If I go that way, this means that each time a page loads, it will go in my session bean to look if it needs to build the favorites list.  I feel it's a bit of an overload: I'd rather build the list once, when the user logs in.

Is that possible or I should keep the beforePageLoad code just as it is now?  Any ideas/thoughts are appreciated.

Comment: I would say that you are doing it right.  Building in the beforePageLoad should result in just building it once.  Have code that checks if it is there, if not then rebuild it.

Comment: I wanted to clarify a bit on xInvolve project. I'm keeping user favorite list in a sessionScope variable. On beforePageLoad event I'm calling a SSJS method `prepareMyFavorites()`. This has two modes, force=true/false. If false, it just check if sessionScope list has been prepared before. beforePageLoad calls the method as (force=false/nothing). When you mark any content as favorite, I save it and calling the same method with (force=true) so it reloads everything from the database.

Comment: That's a little bit confusing because of the user key. First, I use a cookie to determine the user. That mechanism is to allow users to see their favorites even they are not logged in for their subsequent visits. This project is a little bit old. So there are some 'bad-coding' practices there. I'm working on better version of it right now.

Comment: Serdar, I saw what you did and found it great, but I was wandering if there were an event that could be used to trap the login.  Your code is great and I'll probably end up using something directly inspired from it.  :)

Comment: Serdar, can't wait for the new version, as I also need to implement a rating solution!!!

Comment: Thx Ben. I'm glad you liked it. If you show the list of from a View, partial refresh will do some caching. That's why you need to have a different strategy. Lazy-loading will be your solution. You don't have to prepare the list of favorite for a specific user when s/he logged in, instead, you can load it on its first use...

Comment: For the new version, I'm working on a plugin solution. Rating plugin will the first release but it would take a couple of weeks because of the time limitation :(

Answer (score 1):

Note this does NOT actually trap the login.. I'm not sure how to do that exactly but I'm not sure it's nexessary..

Just thinking out loud here.. but I would try this..

Assume you have a "UserObject" to hold the favorites for the user.. then the object gets loaded it reads them in etc...

What about an "App Bean"..  a managed bean in app scope... basically a factory for your application...   inside the AppBean you have a Map...  so that's an easy way to get a hold of the userobject anytime and it lives throughout the app scope...
Now on each page.. you try to grab the UserObject...  if it doesn't exist.. you load it once into the App Bean so it's there for later...  if it exists.. it's already loaded...  you then update the UserObject when the user adds/removes a favorite...  make sure to go through the object in the app bean to keep it updated...

An advantage of this is if the user opens another browser or tab.. it all pulls from the AppBean...

Give that some thought and let me know if you need any help...

Also note:  This is a java solution... it might be workable in SSJS though..

Comment: Basically what David explains will work. You need an app-scoped bean that maintains a Map object for every users. When any user calls for his/her own favorites (anywhere), it should check the Map. If it exists, should return it. Otherwise, it will load the list from the database. You don't need to intercept the login event here. This is called *lazy loading*, pretty much similar to what I did in xInvolve. In xInvolve, I needed to use sessionScope variable. You don't have the control on sessionScope, so no lazy loading will work there. That's why I had to use beforePageLoad in there.

Comment: David, I don't want to have users in the app bean as this application will be used by a huge number of users.  I am afraid that it might cause memory and/or performance issues on the server.  Having the favorites in the session bean will at least free up memory when the session is closed.

Comment: Ben, yes, it will take a huge memory. Then you can use sessionScope for a bean and each bean stores the 'current user's favorite. Again you can utilize lazy-loading. Prepare your list in the constructor of the sessionScope bean. It will be loaded when it's used for the first time. "Mark/Unmark" process should be done within that specific bean so that you can keep it updated.

Answer (score 0):

A standard login page is HTTP only, not XPages. HTTP identifies that a login is required, validates credentials, checks the URL that you're redirecting to exists and only then does the XPages runtime take over.

If you want to trap login, you need to have an XPage making an AJAX request to do the login.

You might want to have a look at XPages Help Application on OpenNTF. I built a favouriting function into that. Favourites are stored in the person's profile, but for the duration of the session held in memory in a Map. The person's profile is created with the hashed value of the username. There is a potential issue with renames, but that's not a significant issue.

Comment: Paul, I guess your favorites work in a very similar way as the ones in the xSnippets/xInvolve app: they are stored in a session managed bean.  I will go that route too, but I was just wandering if there were an event for the login.  I just downloaded the app and will have a look  :)

Answer (score 0):

You could use a *SessionListener*. In the *sessionCreated* method you can calculate the List and initialize your session scoped bean:

```
public class MySessionListener implements SessionListener {

    public void sessionCreated(ApplicationEx arg0, HttpSessionEvent event) {
        FavBean bean = new FavBean();

        // create the favorites List
        // and push it to your bean 

        // add the bean to session scope
        event.getSession().setAttribute("favBean", bean);

    }

    public void sessionDestroyed(ApplicationEx arg0, HttpSessionEvent event) {}

}
```